# Custom Cell Format is not working with VBA output

Tags: excel, formatting, format, refresh, cell

I have a cell **A1** with a custom format like:
**"Max core temperature: "@"°C**     "

Macro below writes data to **A1**, but the custom format is not working.
If only I enter inside the cell manually, then it works.

How can I show the data in **A1** like **Max core temperature:90°C** by macro without doing another extra action like entering to inside the cell.

```
Sub myMacro()
    Range("A1").Value = 90
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it's a string format you need you put the 90 in quotes so that it's not treated as a number.

```
Sub myMacro()
    Range("A1").Value = "90"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works.
Normally I was getting the data from an array which is a Variant data type.
I've changed my code by adding space char like & "" (make it string data type):

wsD0.Cells(9, 7) = myArrayDatasheetHeader(i, 6) & ""